# Block a class in a Iframe

Tags: php, class, iframe, block

I have a Iframe in my site with an other site in it.
But there is some content on that page that I don't want to display, and that content has a specific class. But how can i set that the iframe don't show that class?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to remove the class.

$("iframe .certainclass").removeClass("certainclass");